# How can I include this in a Jquery lightbox or dialog box?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is this technically possible in Jquery .. Basically I'd like to call a php page inside or a lightbox or a Jquery Dialog pop up when a user clicks on an image hyperlink or a link

For example , I have this this line of code .. Once a user clicks on this image link , a dialog or light box should appear with the content of the `profiles.php` page .. How can I implement this in Jquery .. I'm too new to Jquery .. but how would I go about doing this ? I'd really appreciate it .. I need guidance on how to make the profiles.php info load into a dialog or lightbox .. whichever of the two options is appropriate for it.

```
echo "<a href='profiles.php'><img src='boy.jpg'width='100' height='100' class='image' /></a>";
```

Comment: Check this out. http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Comment: that's not helping much unfortunately ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Fancybox ! Its a jquery plugin!

For usage instructions visit : http://fancybox.net/howto

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.load(url) method read more: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
jQuery('a.linkclass').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();// prevent link default action
    jQuery('selection of where you need to load content').load('profiles.php');
});
```

Not sure if it works 100% haven't tested it

Comment: I'd like the popup effect though

Answer (score 0):

1. Load [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) on your page
2. add class `colorbox-html` to the hyperlink
3. add `<script>$('a.colorbox-html').colorbox();</script>` to the bottom of your page
4. Click the link

Disclaimer: This hasn't been tested